# How to check AzureServiceBus availability

Tags: c#, azureservicebus

I currently check the availability of Azure ServiceBus with following code:

```
using Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging;
public static bool IsOnline(string queueName = null)
{
    try
    {
        QueueClient queueClient = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(ConnectionString);
        queueClient.Peek(); //works, but will explode on Receive()
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

However, when ASB queue is disabled, `Peek()` still works but `Receive()` will throw an error.

`Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessagingEntityDisabledException: Messaging entity 'servicebus01:Queue:myqueue' is currently disabled. fc088ddd-0592-460e-a8b1-9587f708a6a1_G30 ---> System.ServiceModel.FaultException1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]:...`

Is there a reliable way to check whether ServiceBus is available ? (online, not disabled, and ready to queue/dequeue)

Comment: You're testing state of an entity, not availability of the Service Bus service itself.

Comment: @SeanFeldman what is the correct way to test ?

Answer (score 1):

Monitoring entity (queue) shouldn't be performed. If an entity is disabled, it has to have a good reason for that. If an entity is disabled, it would be done deliberately, knowing the consequences. Only if *that's* the case, I'd go with an agreed upon protocol how to communicate it, rather than pinging an enntity.

Service availability is a different thing. If you want to make sure that the service is up, is it a one time check or for each operation? If for each operation, you better rely on the built in retry strategy and if needed, add your own back off strategy. If you need to have to action whenever the service is down, you might want to look into the [Azure Monitor service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-overview-azure-monitor).

Comment: What actually happen is sometimes ASB gives timeout or connectivity error. I need a programmatical way to detect its availability first before dequeuing the message. RabbitMQ has `IsOpen` property on its channel to detect this availability. Need to implement similar functionality for ASB.

Comment: When you receive a message, the client has a built in retries strategy. You can also retry on your own in addition to the built in retries. As a matter of fact, Microsoft has [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messaging-exceptions) what to do when messaging exceptions are thrown..

Comment: I cannot believe `Peek()` works when the ServiceBus is unavailable. It is counter intuitive.

Comment: I think you mean "namespace is unavailable". Why not to raise an issue for the brokern in the [official repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/issues).

Comment: Thank you for your pointer. I have raised the issue: https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/issues/147

Answer (score 0):

So far I have the following solution to detect availability:

1. Create a dedicated testqueue
2. Receive message from that queue

Although it works, it feels like a hacky way to reliably detect AzureServiceBus availability. Looking forward to a more elegant solution from you.

```
    public static bool IsOnline(string queueName = null)
    {
        try
        {
            QueueClient queueClient = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(ConnectionString, "testqueue", ReceiveMode.ReceiveAndDelete);
            queueClient.Receive(TimeSpan.Zero);
            queueClient.Close();
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```